# JAX-RS @Context HttpHeaders always null

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

I have a Spring Boot application using jax-rs with resteasy (3.0.24). I'm trying to get the `HttpHeaders` for a request as such:

```
    @DELETE
    @Path("/myendpoint")
    public Response myMethod(@Context HttpHeaders headers, @Context HttpServletRequest request) {
       // headers is always null
    }
```

The headers param is always null even though I'm making the request with multiple headers. As an alternative, I'm extracting them via the `HttpServletRequest.getHeaderNames()`, but I'd really like know why headers is not populated.

Answer (score 1):

Found the (embarrassing, although I deflect the blame to the author:)) error. `@Context HttpHeaders headers` was using Spring's implementation and not that from jax-rs.

Comment: Now that `@Context` will be removed in JAX-RS 4.0, do you know the equivalent formulation for `@Inject`?

Answer (score 0):

You gotta get the headers using the @Context then check if the one one you want is there.

```
@Path("/users")
public class UserService {

@GET
@Path("/get")
public Response addUser(@Context HttpHeaders headers) {

    String userAgent = headers.getRequestHeader("user-agent").get(0);

    return Response.status(200)
        .entity("addUser is called, userAgent : " + userAgent)
        .build();

}
```

}

Comment: You didn't read the post properly. The variable `headers` is `null` when the request comes in, so I can't use it for anything.

Comment: well how does your request look like and where are you requesting from

Comment: `curl -X DELETE  http://localhost/myendpoint -H 'content-type: application/json'  -d '["somePayload"]'`

Comment: yeah your curl delete is in the wrong order it should be                                                           
                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                
 ex: curl -X DELETE -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "Content-type: application/xml" -u [USER:PASS] --cacert [CERT] -d "<action><force>true</force></action>" https://[RHEVM-Host]:443//api/vms/082c794b-771f-452f-83c9-b2b5a19c039

Comment: curl -X DELETE  -H "content-type: application/json"' -d "['somePayload']"' http://localhost/myendpoint

Comment: No, it doesn't matter. The request is made either way. Like I said, I'm hitting the endpoint with no problems. The method is invoked and `HttpServletRequest request` is not null so I can retrieve the headers using that object, but `HttpHeaders httpHeaders` is always null. I get the same results if I use a client like PostMan.

Comment: think it does matter because once it reaches the url part it throws away the rest of your request, yes the request is made but the headers you set are not sent.

Comment: I repeat, I can get ALL the headers (curl or postman) using the `HttpServletRequest` object. None of the headers are being thrown away - I've verified this over and over. If they were being discarded, I would not be able to extract them from `HttpServletRequest request`. However the `HttpHeaders headers` object is null - which makes no sense; if `request` is populated with the headers, then `headers` should be as well.